# update failed java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, ide, filenotfoundexception

i updated my ide to letest version after update i opend project on which i was working before update but it gave error but when i opend other projects there had no error
please help Thank you

```
update failed for AnAction(com.intellij.execution.ExecutorRegistryImpl$ExecutorAction) with ID=Run
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Android\WhatsApp\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file\debug\..\..\apk\debug\output-metadata.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:75)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just clean project and make a build

Answer (score 6):

It is solved by just rebuild project
Build → Rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: if you encounter this error generating an APK, first clean the project (Build -> Clean project)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project.
2. If your project files are not loaded and instead you see: 'Loading...' cancel Sync Gradle by clicking on X at the bottom, this should show your files back.
3. Clean Project: Build -> Clean Project
4. Rebuild Project: Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was unable to Clean Project as well as Sync Gradle Files, So
Eventually I was about to give up, but then I went to

`AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/app/build/intermediates/apk_ide_redirect_file/debug` in the file explorer and found a file named `redirect`
That file contained the following information

```
#- File Locator -
listingFile=../../apk/debug/output-metadata.json
```

From here, I tried to locate the path mentioned in this file and I was unable to find it
So I searched `output-metadata` in the file explorer from `AndroidStudioProjects/project_name` and I found a bunch of `output-metadata` files, I copied the first one and pasted it in the mentioned location, and then everything worked perfectly

Now I don't know wether this is the right way to solve this or not, but it worked...
Hope it helps you...